# How to count the number of active days in a dataset with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

SQL Server 2008, rendered in html via aspx webpage.

What I want to achieve, is to get an average per day figure that makes allowance for missing days. To do this I need to count the number of active days in a table.

Example:

```
Date       | Amount    
---------------------
2014-08-16 | 234.56    
2014-08-16 | 258.30  
2014-08-18 | 25.84  
2014-08-19 | 259.21
```

The sum of the lot (777.961) divided by the number of active days (3) would = 259.30

So it needs to go "count number of different dates in the returned range"

Is there a tidy way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output here? Please indicate the row(s) of output you want based on that data. Also what determines whether a day is 'active'?

Comment: I want the single figure represented above as 259.30: the average per day, across active days. So, if monday, tuesday and wednesday were trading days, and invoices were loaded on those days, then the average would be sum(amount) / distinct SUM(date). But if thursday was a holiday, and then Friday was trading again, I'd want the new SUM(amount) / [only the days represented in the data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want that one row of output then this should work:

```
select sum(amount) / count(distinct date) as your_average
from your_table
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ffd1/1/0

Answer (score -1):

I don't know this will be help to you, how about using Group By, Avg, count function.

```
SELECT Date, AVG(Amount) AS 'AmountAverage', COUNT(*) AS 'NumberOfActiveDays'
FROM YourTable WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY Date
```

About AVG function, see here: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/ms177677.aspx)

Comment: `WITH(NOLOCK)` [stop doing this](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).